# Submit button action points to url "A" but when you click, it takes you to home page

Tags: php, laravel

Just started learning to make websites on laravel and I'm stuck on a form submit button.

This is the code for my form button which is meant to create a post on the "public/hangout" page:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'HangoutController@index']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('subtitle', 'Description:') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('subtitle', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Create Hangout',['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I view the source code on the page I see this:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/hojusoju/public/hangout" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="bcZqiGHKc1cJUDW6c0LbihDDnO5XpWnxCTFcZhEA">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="title" type="text" id="title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subtitle">Description:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="subtitle" cols="50" rows="10" id="subtitle"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Create Hangout">
    </div>

</form>
```

The action URL is correct but when I click on it, it takes me to "localhost/hojusoju/public" and not "public/hangout"? Any ideas?

This is my route.php incase it helps.

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');

Route::get('hangout','HangoutController@index');
Route::get('hangout/create','HangoutController@create');
Route::get('hangout/{id}','HangoutController@show');
Route::post('hangout', 'HangoutController@store');
```

Comment: Is there a redirect in the controller's store method? Go to Hangout Controller and look at the store method, I  bet there is a redirect to the root page.

Comment: you genius :) 

Thank you so much hahahaha - totally missed that. you're the best thanks.